# Problema al actualizar contenido de una variable de session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, php5

En una variable de session array guardo objetos

En una tabla despliego la información que tengo en la variable de session array

```
<table border="0" style="width: 80%;" align="center">
<tr>
<td style="width: 10px;">ID</td>
<td style="width: 200px;">Persona</td>
<td style="width: 15px;">Edad</td>
<td style="width: 20px;">Status</td>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($_SESSION["personas"] as $persona)
{
    if($persona["edad"] >= 18)
        $status = "Adulto";
    else if($persona["edad"] >= 15)
        $status = "Adolescente";
    else if($persona["edad"] >= 60)
        $status = "Veterano";
    else
        $status = "Niño";
?>
  <tr class="persona">
   <td class="td_id"><?php echo $persona["id"]; ?><input type="hidden" class="id_personaVal" value="<?php echo $persona["id"]; ?>"></td>
   <td class="td_nombre"><?php echo $persona["nombre"]; ?></td>
   <td class="td_edad"><input type="text" class="edadVal" value="<?php echo $persona["edad"]; ?>"></td>
   <td class="td_status"><?php echo $status; ?></td>
  </tr>  
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

La columna edad tiene un input text cuando modifico el valor de ese componente se debe de modificar el valor en la variable de session array.

Este es mi codigo que tengo al momento

Código Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    asiganrListener();
});

function asiganrListener()
{
   $(".td_edad").on("keyup", function(){
     var id_persona = $(this).parent(0).children(".td_id").children(".id_personaVal").val() * 1.0;
     var edad = $(this).children(".edadVal").val() * 1.0;

     modificar(id_persona, edad);
   });
}

function modificar(id_persona, edad)
{
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "modificar.php",
       data: "id_persona=" + id_persona + "&edad=" + edad, 
       success: function(data)
       {    
          alert(data);
       }            
   });
}
```

Código modificar.php

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
# id_persona
# edad

session_start();

$cont = 0;

foreach($_SESSION["personas"] as $persona);
{
    if($persona["id"] == $id_persona)
    {
        $_SESSION["personas"][$cont]["edad"] = $edad;
        break;
    }

    $cont++;
}

echo 1;
?>
```

El problema es que no modifica correctamente, si trato de modificar el primer elemento no lo hace, pero si modifico el segundo elemento modifica el primero.

Me marca este error:

> Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Sessiones y Cookies\modificar.php on line 15

Comment: No entiendo por qué usas un bucle para modificar ¿? ¿Por qué no accedes al dato directamente usando su índice?

Comment: @A.Cedano y como haria para saber a que indice voy  acceder, si no estoy mandado ningun indice??

Comment: En lugar de hacer esto: `if($persona["id"] == $id_persona) ...` puedes hacer algo así: `if (isset($_SESSION["personas"]["id"][$id_persona])){ $_SESSION["personas"][$cont]["edad"] = $edad;}` A eso me refiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un punto y coma (;) en el foreach. Puedes pasar el array por referencia

```php
<?php

extract($_POST);
session_start();

foreach($_SESSION["personas"] as &$persona){
    if($persona["id"] == $id_persona) {
        $persona["edad"] = $edad;
        break;
    }
}
echo 1;
```

Comment: Efectivamente el error estaba en que en el foreach después del cierre del paréntesis tenía un punto y coma (;)